# Test If WP_Query Object Is Empty

Tags: wordpress

How can I test to see if a WP_Query object does not return any matches? I'd like to be able to do something like this is a template:

```
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'biographies'))
    if( ***HOW DO I TEST $my_query HERE*** ) {
        //if $my_query finds anything loop through it here
    } else {
        //if $my_query does not find anything            
    }
?>
```

## EDIT

Better example, I want to only display the h2 if the query finds anything:

```
<?php
    $outside_leasing_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'resin_biographies', 'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'taxonomy' => 'resin_buildings', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $page_slug ),
        array( 'taxonomy' => 'resin_leasing_companies', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'rubenstein-partners', 'operator' => 'NOT IN' )
    ) )); // resin_buildings taxonomy term slug must match page slug
?>

<h2>Outside Leasing Contacts</h2>

<?php while ( $outside_leasing_query->have_posts() ) : $outside_leasing_query->the_post(); ?>

    <article <?php post_class('group'); ?>>
        <?php
        if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_biography_headshot', true ) != '' ) {
            echo '<img class="contact-thumb" src="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_biography_headshot', true ) . '" alt="'. get_the_title() .'" />';
        } else {
            echo '<img class="contact-thumb-placeholder" src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/default_headshot.jpg" alt="'. get_the_title() . '" />';
        }
        ?>
        <div class="contact-info">
            <hgroup>
                <?php the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' ); ?>
                <h4 class="contact-title"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_biography_title', true ); ?></h4>
            </hgroup>
            <div class="contact-address"><?php echo wpautop( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_biography_address', true ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="contact-tel"><span>T</span> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_biography_tel', true ); ?></div>
            <?php if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_biography_fax', true ) != '' ) { ?>
                <div class="contact-fax"><span>F</span> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_biography_fax', true ); ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="contact-email"><a href="mailto:<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_biography_email', true ); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_biography_email', true ); ?></a></div>
        </div>
    </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 9):

The standard Wordpress Loop does this for you using have_posts().

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'biographies'));
if($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>
<!-- YOUR POST(S) -->
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<p>No posts found</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Right, but I am looking to display non-query information on the page depending on if the the query has any content. This information is displayed in a different part of the page along side the actually query. So I want to create a single WP_Query object at the top of the page, and then output the information at multiple parts of the page.

Is the best way to do this just to make the WP_Query object at the top, then have multiple while loops on the page?

Comment: Added a new example of what I am actually trying to do.

Comment: I am using the same but my have_posts() method returns Boolean true while loop has no posts.

Answer (score 5):

I figure you could use:

!($my_query->have_posts())

so:

```
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'biographies'))
    if( !($my_query->have_posts())) {
        //if $my_query finds anything loop through it here
    } else {
        //if $my_query does not find anything            
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

In your first example, where you have the comment:

```
//if $my_query does not find anything
```

Just set a parameter like this:

```
$my_query_found_something = 'not';
```

Then use it wherever you need like this:

```
if ($my_query_found_something == 'not') {
// keep looking
}
```