# Don't show $terms if NOT in date range?

Tags: php, date, wordpress, args

I have an archive template that i'm using for a CPT to show posts in a date range.
The probem is this - it still shows the 'term' name on the front-end when a term has a post , but is not in that date range ?

I had this template working before and terms without posts didn't show , but after adding the date range args , the term heading now shows even though no post are in that date range.

I think it's behaving as expected , because there is an actual post in that term , it's just not in the right date range , so the term heading shows up with no posts beneath it.

How can i modify the code below to NOT show the any term heading OR posts that are not in the date range ?

```
<?php


// Remove stuff
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_post_meta' );

// Add our custom loop
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'newsletter_archive_loop' );

// Add our custom loop
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'newsletter_archive_loop' );
function newsletter_archive_loop() {
?>


<?php //start by fetching the terms for the year-groups taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( 'year-groups', array(
'hide_empty' => 'true'
 ) );
?>
<?php

// now run a query for each year-group
foreach( $terms as $term ) {

// Define the query
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'newsletters',
'year-groups' => $term->slug ,
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'after'     => 'July 31st, 2014',
        'before'    => array(
            'year'  => 2015,
            'month' => 8,
            'day'   => 1,
        ),
        'inclusive' => true,
    ),
),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// output the term name in a heading tag               
echo'<h2 class="archive-heading">' . $term->name . '</h2>';

$columns = 3;
$increment = 0; 

    // Start the Loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
    $attachment_id = ( genesis_get_custom_field( 'newsletter_upload_pdf' ) );
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
    $title = get_the_title( $attachment_id );

?>

    <div class="one-third <?php if($increment % $columns == 0){echo'first';}$increment++; ?>">
            <div class="archive-file">
         <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"  target="_blank"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>


    <?php endwhile;?>

     <hr/>
<?php

// use reset postdata to restore orginal query
wp_reset_postdata();


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're echoing the term name outside of the loop, without any checks on the `WP_Query` return value. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10953135/1230836), a simple fix would be:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<h2 class="archive-heading">' . $term->name . '</h2>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->to_post();
        //rest of while loop here
    endwhile;
} else {
    //no else, or:
    echo '<h5>', $term->name, ' - nothing found</h5>';
}
```

There's also a slightly more abstract example of this [on the official WP documentation pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts).
Bottom line is: don't echo the `$term->name` value unless `$query->have_posts()` returns `true`. So in a more WordPress-y style, your code should be:

```
<?php
if ($query->has_posts) :
    <h2 class="archive-heading"><?= $term->name; ?></h2>
    <?php
    while ($query->has_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        //do stuff
    endwhile;
else:
    <!-- <?= $term->name; ?> is empty, optional output here -->
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Remove stuff
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_post_meta' );

// Add our custom loop
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'newsletter_archive_loop' );
function newsletter_archive_loop() {

//start by fetching the terms for the year-groups taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( 'year-groups', array(
    'hide_empty' => 'true'
) );

// now run a query for each year-groups
foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    // Define the query
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'newsletters',
    'year-groups' => $term->slug ,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'July 31st, 2014',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2015,
                'month' => 8,
                'day'   => 1,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

// run the query 
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ) { 

    // output the term name in a heading tag               
    echo'<h2 class="archive-heading">' . $term->name . '</h2>';

    $columns = 3;
    $increment = 0; 

        // Start the Loop
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
        $attachment_id = ( genesis_get_custom_field( 'newsletter_upload_pdf' ) );
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
        $title = get_the_title( $attachment_id );

    ?>

        <div class="one-third <?php if($increment % $columns == 0){echo'first';}$increment++; ?>">
            <div class="archive-file">
         <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"  target="_blank"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>

     <?php endwhile;?>

<hr/>

<?php 
}  
}        
    // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```